# C# solving with Iteration

Tags: c#, loops, iteration

I need to make code in console  that will make the number of the line appear on the line its self and also its position on the line. My program only outputs one single line of ***** and I cant seem to make it make more. Help would be amazing thanks heaps in advance

```
eg 1*****
   *2****
   **3***
   ***4**
```

I currently have,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = 0;
    string s = "";

    //check if 2 args
    if (args.Length == 2)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(args[0], out n))
        {
            //successful parse, so use n
            s = args[1]; //second argument is character

            //draw a line of characters
            DrawChars(n, s);
        }
        else
        {
            //unsuccessful parse, so no n value
        }
    }

    //wait for user to have read output
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Press enter to finish:");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

/// <summary>
/// Method to draw a line of characters
/// </summary>
/// <param name="n">number of characters to draw</param>
/// <param name="s">character to draw n times</param>
static void DrawChars(int n, string s)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(s);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: s= "" not " D "        and ive set n as 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code only prints one line.  You need an outer loop to print multiple lines, plus a conditional check to know whether to print the row number or the string in the appropriate column of the line.

Change your `DrawChars(int n, string s)` to

```
/// <summary>
/// Method to draw a line of characters
/// </summary>
/// <param name="n">number of characters to draw</param>
/// <param name="s">character to draw n times</param>
static void DrawChars(int n, string s)
{
    for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col <= n; col++)
        {
            Console.Write(col == row ? col.ToString() : s);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DrawChars(5, "*");
```

Results:

```
1****
*2***
**3**
***4*
****5
```

Answer (score 0):

If I can understand your requirement properly, you can use nested for loop to print:

```
static void Main()
        {
            const int maxLineNumber = 5;
            for (var itr = 1; itr <= maxLineNumber; itr++)
            {
                for (var innerItr = 1; innerItr <= maxLineNumber; innerItr++)
                {
                    if (innerItr == itr)
                    {
                        Console.Write(itr);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

It'll print:

```
1****
*2***
**3**
***4*
****5
```